# Is it possible to file a capture template in a subheading of a day in a datetree?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

In Org-mode, I would like to have a capture template get stored like this:

```
* 2015
** 2015-05 May
*** 2015-05-21 Thursday     <--- I can get this with file+datetree
**** Todo today             <--- here's the problem
***** TODO something        <--- this is the captured content
```

Is that possible out of the box? If not, any ideas how to go about implementing it?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what it is you want to achieve. Why is there a "problem" in the line that says `**** Todo today`? It would be great if you could extend your post to include (1) an example of the output that your capture template currently produces, (2) a *separate* example of the output you would like to see, and (3) the capture template itself. Other than that, welcome to Emacs.SE!

Comment: I don't know how to get that line between the datetree headline (`2015-05-21 Thursday`) and the headline produced by the template (`TODO something`). Basically, what I need is `file+datetree+olp`.

Comment: In case you saw the answer I posted earlier: It did not fully address your use case in the sense that it inserted a `**** Todo today` heading for every `TODO` item created using `org-capture`. I have since fixed this issue; please have another look at my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by defining a custom function that returns the target location for template expansion:

```el
(defun org-find-heading-in-datetree ()
  (org-datetree-find-date-create (calendar-current-date))
  (goto-char (point-at-eol))
  (when (not (re-search-forward
              (format org-complex-heading-regexp-format
                      (regexp-quote "Todo today")) nil t))
    (insert "\n**** Todo today\n"))
  (goto-char (point-max)))
```

Then set your template up like this:

```el
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Test" plain (file+function "~/org/test.org"
                                         org-find-heading-in-datetree)
         "***** TODO %?")))
```

Comment: `calendar-current-date` is Gregorian at the outset, so no need to convert from `org-today` to Gregorian.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for pointing that out! I updated my answer.

Comment: This almost worked for me. The problem was that it would add the "***** Todo today" but then the "***** TODO" would be outside the datetree. Was able to fix this behavior by changing (goto-char (point-max)) to (goto-char (point-at-eol))