# Org-capture - placing entry in user-specified subheading

Tags: org-capture

I am trying to create a capture-template which will prompt the user to define a subheading so that it can place the capture as a level 3 heading under the appropriate level 2 heading within an org file.  For example:

`* Classes
 ** CLASSNAME1
 *** SOME ENTRY
 ** CLASSNAME2
 *** SOME ENTRY`

I want to be able to specify in the mini buffer whether a capture will be added as a level 3 heading to one of the two level 2 headings `CLASSNAME1` or `CLASSNAME2`.

I have found somewhat similar questions posted about this but none have actually solved my issue.

My template is currently as follows:

`("c" "Class" entry
      (file+olp "~/gtd/tickler.org" "Classes" org-get-classname)
      "* %^{Class Type}\nSCHEDULED: %^{Class time1}T-%^{Class time2}T\n:LOCATION: %^{Location}\n")`

(The level 1 heading `* Classes` is within the file: `~/gtd/tickler.org`)

My `org-get-classname` function looks like:

`(defun org-get-classname ()
  (setq subheading-name (read-string "Enter subheading: "))
  (subheading-name))`

I am simply trying to prompt the user for the name of the level 2 heading with `org-get-classname` and then use that to add the capture as a level 3 heading.

Currently, when trying to use this capture-template I am told:

`Wrong type argument: stringp, org-get-classname`

I have been playing around with `file+function` as well but have not found any success with that either.

This is my first week trying out emacs so I am very new at this point, and I do not have prior experience with elisp so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The error msg tells you that Emacs evaluated the symbol `org-get-classname` as a variable, and found that its value was not a string (a string was expected). Where are you setting its value? You say it's a *function*. Did you mean to quote it, so you pass it as a symbol (whose function value is used)? Or did you mean to put it in parens, to invoke it as a functions?

Comment: @Drew I'm trying to evaluate the `org-get-classname` within the template so that when the template is used the user has to specify which level 2 heading they want the capture to be placed in.  From what I understand, `org-get-classname` should return whatever string the user inputs and I want that to go in place of the `org-get-classname` evaluation within the template.

Comment: But you show that it's a function, not a variable, yet your code uses it as a variable. Please reread my comment. Do you want `'org-get-classname` (pass the symbol, so the caller can, e.g., invoke the function) or `(org-get-classname)` (call the function, returning its value) or `org-get-classname` (evaluate it as a variable). You're doing the last of these - is that appropriate?

Comment: @Drew I think that I want to be invoking the function to use the returned value but I tried both `'org-get-classname` and `(org-get-classname)` and I got similar error messages to my original implementation: for `'org-get-classname`: `Wrong type argument: stringp, (quote org-get-classname)` and for `(org-get-classname)`: `Wrong type argument: stringp, (org-get-classname)`.

Comment: I believe you want `file+function` rather than `file+olp`.  One example of use is at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12577/2710 .  You will need to use `read-string` or `completing-read` to get the input from the user.